# Content disposition file name nor working in java

Tags: google-chrome, content-type, content-disposition

I have a code downloading excel, where I have content type as application/vnd.ms-excel and content disposition as below
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FILENAME.xls

In INTERNET Explorer I'm getting expected file but in chrome it's downloading plain text having all the content in excel as .file format

Please provide any suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have tried keeping the filename in "", but no luck

Comment: Please attach the full HTTP response; in particular: what is the Content-Type?